# The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null' how to add condition

Tags: flutter, api, dart

how can I solve this problem. I know there are a lot of  answers about this problem in internet. But I could not adapt them.
My code for get values from WordPress website with WordPress own API.

file 1  main.dart

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'wp-api.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(benimApp());
}

class benimApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(children: [
            xMyHomePage(),
          ]),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class xMyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: FutureBuilder(
            future: fetchWpPosts(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: 4,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                
                    Map wppost = snapshot.data[index];     
                                // return Text(wppost['title']['rendered']);
                  },
                );
              }
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

file 2 wp-api.dart

```
  import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

Future<List> fetchWpPosts() async {
  final response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse('https://www.yazilimaktif.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed'));
  var convertDataJson = jsonDecode(response.body);
  return convertDataJson;
}
```

I am getting error like this title

Comment: how about `Future<List?> fetchWpPosts() async {` so its nullable

add the question mark after lis, to make it return null when no data

Comment: or `return convertDataJson  ?? [ ]; `

so its return empty list if the response is null

Comment: I try put ? to Future<List?> but still same error.

Answer (score 1):

Have you try with a return type of `Future<List<dynamic>>`, like this:

```
  Future<List<dynamic>> fetchWpPosts() async {
  try {
    final response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse('https://www.yazilimaktif.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed'));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var convertDataJson = jsonDecode(response.body);
      return convertDataJson;
    } else {
      return [];
    }
  }
  catch (error) {
    return [];
  }
}
```

And add default value in case of errors to be sure don't returning null value.

Comment: still same error. Thanks for help

Comment: Can you provide stasck trace?

Comment: What, I don't understand your question, sorry.

Comment: Error print by flutter must indicate where the error is and some informations, can ou provide these informations?

Comment: Or is this error from source code editor?

Comment: (Line 39 Column 49).  Map wppost = snapshot.data*[*index]; there is error in between stars. red underline place

Comment: I updated my response give it a try

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that data returned from snapshot is optional.
So you need to unwrap it or check for null.

Your code will look like this:

```
 FutureBuilder(
        future: fetchWpPosts(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            List<dynamic> returnedList = snapshot.data! as List;

            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: 4,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                Map wppost = returnedList[index];
                return Text(wppost['title']['rendered']);
              },
            );
          }
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }),
```